# What is a delta family?

Tags: functions, distribution-theory, smooth-functions

According to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Tl4.png) passage from Green's Function and Boundary Value Problems, the n-dimensional delta family is defined as {*fa*}, but I still dont understand what the definition of a delta family is. So my question is, what is a delta family in simple terms and is there an example to this delta family? Thankyou

Comment: It's any set of functions $f_{\alpha}$ with the property $\lim_{\alpha} \int f_{\alpha}(x) \phi(x)\,dx = \phi(0)$ for any test function. Effectively what the functions do is pull out the individual values of test functions $\phi$ upon integration (and taking limits). These are often used in regularization arguments and also come up in reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces.

Comment: okay do you mind explaining what limα∫fα(x)ϕ(x)dx=ϕ(0) means and maybe give an example of such a set of functions? thanks :)

Comment: Do you know limits and integrals?

Comment: @curiousboi Here's an example: $f_n = n 1_{[-\frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2n}]}$. Here's another example: $f_{\alpha}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\alpha}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha}}$ (assuming I didn't goof my normalization factor). In some sense, the functions $f$ approximate an infinite spike at the origin. As $n$ or $\alpha$ increases, these functions get narrower and taller at the origin.

Comment: well written and explained, thank you very much